# Page not found error while fetching local file in laravel 7

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, web-development-server

I'm trying to fetch local product description file,
In products page while cone clicks on Read more option for full product description, it shows error404 page not found.

The local product file path is resources/views/html/products/chili.blade.php, here product is chili.

```
<div class="col-md-4 services-grid">
                     <div class="history-grid-image">
                        <img src="images/Chilli Farm.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                     </div>
                     <div class="services-info">
                        <h4>Chili</h4>
                        <p>The Chili pepper is the fruit of plants from the genus capsicum which are members of nightshade family Solanaceae. 
                        <!-- Chili is extremely popular in India as it brings heat to the food. -->
                        <!-- India having a rich history of spices and mostly chili finds a place in every dish of Indian food.<br> -->
                        <!-- Medicinal properties: Capsaicin is the chemical used in plain reliever ointment.
                        Capsaicin also used in pepper spray and tear gas as chemical irritants to control the crowd in an emergency situation. -->
                        <!-- Rich in :  vitamin B6, vitamin A, iron, copper, potassium and a small amount of protein and carbohydrates.<br> -->
                        <!-- Helps in digestion, Weight loss, No Cholesterol Content. -->
                        <!-- Good for Diabetic people. -->
                        <!-- Fact : Chili was first introduced to India by the Portuguese towards the end of the century.</p> -->
                        <a class="more" href="{{ url('products-chili') }}"> Read More</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
```

Here's product description file

```
@extends("layouts.html")

@section("title", "Chili|GreenGoodsExports")

@section("chili")

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<!--banner-->
    <div class="banner-1">

    </div>  
<!--//banner-->
<!--single-page-->
<div class="single">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="tittle-one">Chili</h2>
                <div class="single-page-artical">
                    <div class="artical-content">
                        <h4>Chili</h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/Chilli Farm.jpg" alt=" " style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.5s; animation-name: zoomIn;">
                        <p>The Chili pepper is the fruit of plants from the genus capsicum which are members of nightshade family Solanaceae. 
                        Chili is extremely popular in India as it brings heat to the food.
                        India having a rich history of spices and mostly chili finds a place in every dish of Indian food.<br>
                        Medicinal properties: Capsaicin is the chemical used in plain reliever ointment.
                        Capsaicin also used in pepper spray and tear gas as chemical irritants to control the crowd in an emergency situation.
                        Rich in :  vitamin B6, vitamin A, iron, copper, potassium and a small amount of protein and carbohydrates.<br>
                        Helps in digestion, Weight loss, No Cholesterol Content.
                        Good for Diabetic people.
                        Fact : Chili was first introduced to India by the Portuguese towards the end of the century.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="artical-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>March 10, 2016</span></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>admin</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>No comments</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>View posts</span></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-grid-top">
                        <h3>Responses</h3>
                        <div class="comments-top-top">
                            <div class="top-comment-left">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/co.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="top-comment-right">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span class="left-at"><a href="#">Admin</a></span></li>
                                    <li><span class="right-at">March 10, 2016 at 10.30am</span></li>
                                    <li><a class="reply" href="#">Reply</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comments-top-top top-grid-comment">
                            <div class="top-comment-left">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/co.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="top-comment-right">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span class="left-at"><a href="#">Admin</a></span></li>
                                    <li><span class="right-at">March 18, 2016 at 10.30am</span></li>
                                    <li><a class="reply" href="#">Reply</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                    <div class="artical-commentbox">
                        <h3>leave a comment</h3>
                        <div class="table-form">
                            <form>
                                <input placeholder="Name" type="text" required="">
                                <input placeholder="Email" type="email" required="">    
                                <input placeholder="Phone" type="text" required="">                                 
                                <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                <input type="submit" value="Send">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--single-page-->

</body>
</html>



@endsection
```

Here's web.php code

```
Route::get("/products/chili", "ProductsController@chili")->name('products-chili');
```

Here's ProductsController.php code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function chili() {
        return view("html.products1.chili");
}
```

Please help me out, thanks...

Comment: Is the folder products or products1 ?

Comment: Edit: The local product file path is resources/views/html/products1/chili.blade.php, here product is chili.

Answer (score 0):

In you return view is it not suppose to be

```
 return view("html.products.chili");
```

instead of

```
return view("html.products1.chili");
```

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function chili() {
        return view("html.products.chili");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... Sorry the local product file path is resources/views/html/products1/chili.blade.php, here product is chili.

Comment: Try this at the URL.   replace url() with route().  <a class="more" href="{{ route('products-chili') }}"> Read More</a> </div>

Comment: Thanks Dave, it worked... but i  need one more help, page opened as plain html without css/bootstrap. please help.

Comment: show your file path to your layout file. is your layout file html??? `@extends("layouts.html")` control it

Comment: yes layout file is html.blade.php Path - resources/views/layouts/html.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

For the **@extends('layouts.html')** to be effective there must be a **@yield('chili')** in your html.blade.php which will yield the content of the 'chili' section from your **chili.blade.php** 
NB: html.blade.php contains all the required CSS and JS files
see below:
For your **html.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--include-all-your-head-contents-including-meta-tags-css-links-and-js-->
    @yield('title')
</head>
<body>
    @yield('chili')
    <!--include-all-your-scripts-required-->
</body>
</html>
```

For your **chili.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.html')
@section("title", "Chili|GreenGoodsExports")

@section("chili")
<!--banner-->
    <div class="banner-1">
    </div>  
<!--//banner-->
<!--single-page-->
<div class="single">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="tittle-one">Chili</h2>
                <div class="single-page-artical">
                    <div class="artical-content">
                        <h4>Chili</h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/Chilli Farm.jpg" alt=" " style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.5s; animation-name: zoomIn;">
                        <p>The Chili pepper is the fruit of plants from the genus capsicum which are members of nightshade family Solanaceae. 
                        Chili is extremely popular in India as it brings heat to the food.
                        India having a rich history of spices and mostly chili finds a place in every dish of Indian food.<br>
                        Medicinal properties: Capsaicin is the chemical used in plain reliever ointment.
                        Capsaicin also used in pepper spray and tear gas as chemical irritants to control the crowd in an emergency situation.
                        Rich in :  vitamin B6, vitamin A, iron, copper, potassium and a small amount of protein and carbohydrates.<br>
                        Helps in digestion, Weight loss, No Cholesterol Content.
                        Good for Diabetic people.
                        Fact : Chili was first introduced to India by the Portuguese towards the end of the century.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="artical-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>March 10, 2016</span></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>admin</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>No comments</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>View posts</span></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-grid-top">
                        <h3>Responses</h3>
                        <div class="comments-top-top">
                            <div class="top-comment-left">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/co.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="top-comment-right">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span class="left-at"><a href="#">Admin</a></span></li>
                                    <li><span class="right-at">March 10, 2016 at 10.30am</span></li>
                                    <li><a class="reply" href="#">Reply</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comments-top-top top-grid-comment">
                            <div class="top-comment-left">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/co.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="top-comment-right">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span class="left-at"><a href="#">Admin</a></span></li>
                                    <li><span class="right-at">March 18, 2016 at 10.30am</span></li>
                                    <li><a class="reply" href="#">Reply</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                    <div class="artical-commentbox">
                        <h3>leave a comment</h3>
                        <div class="table-form">
                            <form>
                                <input placeholder="Name" type="text" required="">
                                <input placeholder="Email" type="email" required="">    
                                <input placeholder="Phone" type="text" required="">                                 
                                <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                <input type="submit" value="Send">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--single-page-->
@endsection
```

You can see more here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade